# Странный код с двойным long

Tags: c

Увидел в коде вот такое выражение:

```
long long value = ...;
```

Почему здесь long 2 раза? Это опечатка или такое корректно и действительно что-то значит? Если так, то что изменится, если один long стереть или если, наоборот, дописать еще один?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Из ISO/IEC 9899:1999 (E):

4 There are five standard signed integer types, designated as **signed char**, **short
int**, **int**, **long int**, and **long long in**t. (These and other types may be
designated in several additional ways, as described in 6.7.2.) There may also be
implementation-defined extended signed integer types.28) The standard and extended
signed integer types are collectively called signed integer types.29)

— minimum value for an object of type long int
LONG_MIN -2147483647 // -(2^31 - 1)

— maximum value for an object of type long int
LONG_MAX +2147483647 // 2^31 - 1

— minimum value for an object of type long long int
LLONG_MIN -9223372036854775807 // -(2^63 - 1)

— maximum value for an object of type long long int
LLONG_MAX +9223372036854775807 // 2^63 - 1

Comment: Странно. В этом списке всё равно нет long long, только long long int.

Comment: Ничего странного. Можно ведь написать просто 'long' и компилятор поймет, что речь идет о 'long int'. Т.е. int - это тип по умолчанию.

Comment: Насчет типа по умолчанию -- все верно. Можно только добавить, что long long появился недавно и есть стандартом 2010.

Comment: Опять из стандарта 6.7.2 Type specifiers: ... At least one type specifier shall be given in the declaration specifiers in each declaration,
and in the specifier-qualifier list in each struct declaration and type name. .... — long, signed long, long int, or signed long int
... 
— long long, signed long long, long long int, or
signed long long int

Comment: Кроме одного случая - констант. Если я правильно помню. Можно невозбранно написать const i = 10; Правда, что там за тип переменной получится - хз. Скорее всего double или int.

Comment: @3JIoi_Hy6: `long long` появился в 1999 году в стандарте С99.

Comment: @gecube: Такое допускалось только в классическом С89/90. Начиная с С99 ни о каком `const i` больше не может быть и речи.

Comment: Тот факт, что `long long` эквивалентен `long long int` не является проявлением того, что `int` - якобы тип "по умолчанию". Правило типа по умолчанию в С уже давно отменено. Тем не менее эта эквивалентность сохраняется.

Answer (score 4):

О константах. В комментариях нет форматирования. Поэтому сюда:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    const i = 10000000001;
    printf ("%ld", i);
    return 0;
}

$ gcc -o c -std=c99 c.c
c.c: В функции ‘main’:
c.c:3: предупреждение: в декларации ‘i’ по умолчанию установлен тип ‘int’
c.c:3: предупреждение: переполнение при неявном преобразовании константы
```

тогда как

```
const long long i = 10000000001l;
printf("%lld", i);
```

выводит правильно. gcc 4.3.4

Comment: `const i = 10000000001;` не допускается в С99.

Answer (score 3):

long и short "расширение" (не могу вспомнить/подобрать подходящее слово) для типа int. 
 Т.е. здесь написано long long int, что по идее должно увеличить размер типа, хотя мой компилятор показывает одинаковый размер для long и long long.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
        short int i_1;
        int i0;
        long int i1;
        long long int i2;
        printf("short int = %d\nint = %d\nlong int = %d\nlong long int = %d\n", sizeof(i_1), sizeof(i0), sizeof(i1), sizeof(i2));
        return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
short int = 2
int = 4
long int = 8
long long int = 8
```

Answer (score 3):

Для 64-bit машины и long и long long это 64-х разрядное целое (8 байт), для 32-bit машины long это 32-х разрядное целое (4 байт), а long long 64-х разрядное целое (8 байт).

Вообще, для переносимости так писать правильно.

Comment: Windows с тобой не соглясен.

Comment: @Qwertiy♦: "Согласие" или "не согласие" в таких вопросах целиком и полностью определяется реализацией (компилятором) и никак не связано с ОС. Так что Windows здесь ни при чем.

Comment: @AnT, все компиляторы под Windows сделали 32-битный long. Где-то табличка была.

Comment: @Qwertiy, в винде в самом деле так. Наверное БГ решил когда-то (не знаю уж с какой далеко идущей целью или просто так получилось ...). В мире \*nix long это размер регистра. В винде long -- двойное слово в терминах их терминологии еще 16-битных времен. Короче, long в винде 32 bit даже в 64-bit компах. При этом размер указателя в 64-bit все же размером с регистр. Лучше просто не пишите в такой системе (по крайней мере без значительного вознаграждения)

Answer (score 1):

long long это 64-битное целое, аналог __int64 в Microsoft Visual C++, в то время как просто long - 32-битное целое.